# Как записать три файла, ссылки на которые содержатся в массиве, в один через PHP?

Tags: php

Имеются три файла, ссылки на которые содержатся в массиве `$urls`.
В цикле, который имеется в коде ниже, в `links.xml` записывается только один из файлов. Подскажите, как исправить ситуацию?

```
<?
preg_match_all("/(https\:\/\/www\.ikea\.com\/sitemaps\/prod-ru-RU\_[\d]+\.xml)/", 
file_get_contents('https://www.ikea.com/sitemaps/sitemap.xml'), $urls);

$file = 'links.xml';

foreach ($urls[0] as $url) {
    $threeFile = file_get_contents($url);
    file_put_contents($file, $threeFile);
}
?>
```

Comment: `file_put_contents($file, $threeFile, FILE_APPEND);`
https://www.php.net/file-put-contents

Comment: @RomanGrinyov использовал данный флаг, но не помогло, когда пробовал. Сейчас попробовал ещё раз - и пошел процесс! Чудеса. Благодарю! Оформите, как ответ

Comment: @RomanGrinyov подскажите, пожалуйста, а как при повторном исполнении скрипта сделать так, чтобы уже существующий файл `links.xml` не дополнялся, а перезаписывался? Ставил `fclose($threeFile)` и снаружи цикла и внутри - реакции нет..

Comment: `file_put_contents($file, "")` или `unlink` перед циклом сделайте да и все. а `fclose` вообще к этому не относится

Comment: @QuickBrownFox, так просто уберите флаг `FILE_APPEND` и он будет перезаписываться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы контент файла не перезаписывался, а дополнялся, вам нужно добавить флаг `FILE_APPEND`:

```php
file_put_contents($filename, $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

https://php.net/file-put-contents

[image: Документация]